# Docker mount volume ignores .ini file

Tags: docker, mount

I have created a docker container for my NodeJS app. I store all the server specific info in a **config.ini** file, which I plan to mount when I run the docker container. I use following command to run:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 --name my-app -v config:/usr/src/app/config -d image_name
```

The config folder has 4 files, out of which 1 file's extension is **ini**. When I log into container (using docker exec), **config.ini** file is missing from the mounted directory. All other files are present. When I change the extension of **config.ini** to **config.json** (or anything else), at that time, docker mounts the file. So there is some issue with .ini extension. Following are the environment details:

Mac OS 10.12.5

Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

File permissions in config folder:

> -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 tarun  staff  133 May  1  2016 awsConfig.json
>
> -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 tarun  staff  133 May  1  2016 awsConfig.json.sample
>
> -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 tarun  staff  368 Jul  1  2016 config.ini.sample
>
> -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 tarun  staff  535 Jun 13 12:02 project_config.ini

Is there a docker property which I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your config dir is being referenced wrong. you should have it like:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 --name my-app -v $(pwd)/config:/usr/src/app/config -d image_name
```

This ensures it has full path to directory. Also I'm assuming this directory is in your current working directory hence the `$(pwd)`

If this fixes your issue please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @gbolo ! I was stuck on this since a few days. `$(pwd)` solved it.

Comment: np @tarunmittal